# Python: How to makedirs from an excel file containing paths?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, path, create-directory

## How do I generate folders using the contents of my excel document?

I have been coding this for awhile and I just cannot seem to get it to work.

My objective is to create folders using an excel document which will include paths as displayed here;
[Excel spreadsheet contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11x5B.png)

Excel document is named 'GreeceHoliday2018' and only contains 'Sheet1' located on my Desktop.

My intention was:  **Read the excel document -> read 'Sheet 1' -> print contents -> create a loop with contents to os.makedirs -> New folder (named 'Photos') with subfolders on desktop**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

os. chdir("C:\\Users\\NAME\\desktop")
workbook = pd.ExcelFile('GreeceHoliday2018.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.parse('Sheet1')

print (sheet)

os.getcwd()
path = os.getcwd()


print ("The current working Directory is %s" % path)

try:
        os.makedirs(sheet)

except OSError:
   print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
  print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

The following resulted in this:

`Exception has occurred: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame`

Can anyone help me? I believe there must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: What is the output of sheet? where is the error?

Comment: The error is on line 19: `os.makedirs(sheet)`


The sheet output is:            
                        

`Folder Address`

`0     Photos\Greece\Rhodes`
`1     Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day1\Beach`
`2     Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day1\Family`
`3           Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day1\Hotel`
`4         Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day2\Family`
`5        Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day2\Tourist Sights`
`6  Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day2\Park`
`7               Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day3\Family`
`8           Photos\Greece\Rhodes\Day4\Family`

@Ori

Comment: Take the values somehow, I don't know this object you can try as mentioned below with sheet.values, then you can iterate the values
for folder in folders:
      os.makedirs(folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheet is a `DataFrame` object that contains several attributes, try using `sheet.values` to get the values of the dataframe as a numpy array.

Read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to see all the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Your returned sheet is a pandas Dataframe, that you can iterate over to extract the text from your sheet. You can then call os.makedirs() on each line of the text in your sheet, excluding the first line with the column name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What would be the best way to extract the text? Arrays have already proven problematic when using 'os.makedirs'.

`Exception has occurred: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ndarray`

Comment: os.makedirs() takes in a single string: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-makedirs-method/. The idea is not that you pass it multiple directories, but if you have the path a/b/c/ where dirs b and c don't exist, it creates both of them. If b exists it only creates c. You need to obtain the string for each file path from the dataframe and call os.makedirs() on that.

Comment: you can also mark one of the answers as correct if it helped you